# 3ds collada UV mapping problem in Papervision

Tags: papervision3d, 3dsmax, collada

As I briefly explained in the title, my problem concerns texturing a collada export in papervision.

Basically I was exporting collada models from Cinema 4d with its uv map. I was able to see everything, but the texture was not displaying properly (hidden polygons).

So I decided to try with 3dsMax. I used the same code to display the texture :

```
var materials:MaterialsList = new MaterialsList();
var torusMaterial:BitmapFileMaterial = new BitmapFileMaterial("model/tex.png");
torusMaterial.precise = true;
materials.addMaterial(torusMaterial, "ID1");
```

Again, I can see every elements, but this time my model uses only one pixel of my texture. So if I use a red texture and if I color only the pixel at the left bottom corner in green, all my model will be green.

Any advice about how to properly wrap the texture around a 3ds export model?
Thank you.

Comment: Not enough details to work it out monsieur. Can you check these:

Answer (score 0):

The Autodesk Collada exporter that ships with 3ds max is problematic, and gives .dae output that Papervision doesn't expect. This will be an even worse problem when you get to exporting animation. Try the OpenCollada exporter: http://www.opencollada.org/download.html

Many people have had a lot more luck using it with Papervision3D. Unfortunately it's not yet available for 3ds max 2012 so if you might be stuck if you can't find an older version. Or maybe you can get the source and compile it against 2012? Let the project maintainers know if you do.